# ¿Cómo se pasan parámetros dinámicos en DataBinding de Android?

Tags: android

[DataBinding de Android](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture) parece genial, pero no veo por ningún lado la forma de pasar parámetros dinámicos.

Desde la Vista (Fragmento) yo decido un parámetro de tipo String (que es la fecha), y puede ser la fecha de hoy, pero puede ser otra fecha que el usuario elige desde un calendario.

En la vista tengo por un lado la variable `mDate` declarada como miembro de la clase:

```
private String mDate;
```

Y este método para decidir si es la fecha de hoy u otra pasada desde un calendario:

```
private void pickOutDate() {
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    mDate = (bundle != null) ? bundle.getString("FECHA") : Utils.getHoy();
}
```

Este es el método que llama al `ViewModel` pasándole la fecha:

```
mViewModel.getObservable(mDate).observe(this, dataObserver);
```

En el layout yo estoy intentando esto:

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View" />
    <!-- Only view model required -->
    <variable name="vm"  type="org.deiverbum.app.viewmodel.LecturasViewModel" />
    <variable name="mDate" type="java.lang.String"/>
</data>
```

Y en el `TextView` pongo esto, sin éxito:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@{vm.getObservable(@{mDate})}" />
```

No me deja poner `@{mDate}` como argumento del método en ese contexto.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto sin sacrificar el modelo de datos (por lo dicho en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52988034/5587982))? ¿O DataBinding no existe para este propósito?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entendi, tienes un metodo llamado `getObservable` dentro de tu `viewmodel` y le mandas `mDate` como argumento para generar la fecha correcta.

La sintaxis correcta seria

```
android:text="@{vm.getObservable(mDate)}"
```

pero tendrias que hacer que la funcion `getObservable` regrese un `LiveData`.
Hice una prueba y te dejo el ejemplo

```
android:text="@{viewModel.test(mDate)}"

fun test(num: String): LiveData<String> {
    return liveData {
        //todo, tu logica para evaluar la fecha
        this.emit("hola $num") //en el layout aparece hola y la cadena
    }
}
```

Con eso podrias remover

```
mViewModel.getObservable(mDate).observe(this, dataObserver);
```

Otra forma seria que no mandes a llamar a la funcion dentro de tu layout y hagas algo asi

```
mViewModel.getObservable(mDate).observe(this) { fecha ->
    databinding.textViewFecha.text = fecha
}
```

y te olvidas de tener variables en tu layout

```
<variable name="vm"  type="org.deiverbum.app.viewmodel.LecturasViewModel" />
<variable name="mDate" type="java.lang.String"/>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. El problema es que la fecha no la quiero para mostrarla en el Fragment, la fecha la obtengo en el Fragment y quiero pasarla como parámetro al ViewModel, para que éste se la pase al Repository y éste me obtenga los datos en la Base de Datos o en el servidor remoto o en Firebase según la fecha dada. Todo eso ya funciona, sólo que al ver Databinding pensé si podría pasar la fecha de ese modo y por eso mi pregunta.

Comment: bueno, es que eso es diferente. Ahi podrias usar @AssistedInject para pasar el mDate al repository